# converting html to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Am new in wordpess. I have managed to install wordpress perfectly. I would wish to load an html or php page into wordpress to allow for quicker editing of the content. How can I further open it in wordpress? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This questions is better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add html to your wordpress by using the editor to carry out your intentions.

Here is an image sample.

[image: Edit]

Answer (score 1):

Pages are stored in the database rather than in HTML / PHP files. If you want to customize the layout of content on a page you would have to add a page-.php template to your theme directory.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development Essentially you only need two files for a bare-bones theme: index.php and style.css. The style.css file, at minimum, must have this comment at the top:

```
/*
Theme Name: Whatever you call it
*/
```

The index.php at minimum would have something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Whatever your title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Compress the folder with these two files in a zip file, use theme upload to upload the file, and voila. Your first, "hello world" Wordpress theme is up. I suggest you learn a little more because a lot of code you may put in the files may break, unless is static html with hardcoded links (which beats the purpose of Wordpress) and plain-old css in the stylesheet.

If what you want is add your own code to an already-existing theme there's a tab for adding your HTML snippets in a page or post [image: wordpress HTML edit more]

You can't add php, unless you go to the theme editor on the appearance panel.

If you want to add your own page to a theme you will need to upload page-example.php to the theme folder and add a new page on the dashboard with the name of example. To find your theme folder in your site you will have to dig for your themes folder inside the wp-content folder. I don't recommend this, by the way, just letting you know what you can do.